# Deactivate "fullscreen" mode on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome

The newest version of Chrome for Android added a quasi fullscreen-mode, which hides the address bar when you scroll up. This has weird effects in my web app, which is mainly controlled by scrolling up and down.

Is there a way to keep the address bar visible (the old way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  If you feel that this should be a feature then please file a bug on crbug.com/new and let me know.  It should have no effect on scrolling as it keeps all the settings and state exactly the same, if you are seeing problems with scrolling such as events not firing then that is due to the way the compositor works.

The reason why not is that this is a feature on all mobile platforms and we have parity with their way of providing the user with more vertical real estate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should've explained what I mean by "weird effects". I have a fixed element on the page which in Chrome for Android gets pushed down when the scrollbar gets visible and in Chrome for iOS stays at its initial position. I'll file a bug, if I find the exact reason why.

Comment: @johnny fixed elements with position:fixed should stay fixed to the position in the DOM.  Could you send a test through so I could check?

Comment: @Kinlan - I was able to reproduce this bug. [This is the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owLfeAtAj_E) of the bug itself (look at the page "jumping" at 7sec), and [here is the code](https://gist.github.com/kamituel/e0a0b3fe95c6eb48439b). It uses Bootstrap 2.3.2. Can you file a bug for it?

Comment: @Kinlan - I filled [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=306734&thanks=306734&ts=1381569521) for it.